# SSRS 2008 r2 report with multiple tablixes is cutting the size of the tablix to one third of the page?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a report that I have inherited.  An end user is stating that when the SSRS report is exported to either pdf or excel that it is chopping what was a 4 to 5 page report into a 15 to 16 page report in pdf or excel format.  (there are 5 tablixes on the page)

I am thoroughly confused, as I have never seen this before.  I have been reviewing the properties of the report and of the tablixes but do not see anything out of place.

It looks as if the tablixes are only being allowed 1/3 to 1/4 of the page, I am guessing it is due to a setting.

I have tried report page properties for the size of the page and also, consume white space setting and neither have really helped.

Comment: Could you be more specific about the properties you've fiddled with, or help us reproduce this issue? If all else fails, resort to [binary search debugging](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/181223/40625) to find the root cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after trying every setting in the book.  Finally found that it had to do with the footer property being astronomically large, which you don't see in the rendered preview.